# How to multiply two columns in awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to multiply column 1 with column 2 (till end of file) in input file and should output 1 column and multiplied 3 column in separate file.

input.txt :

```
1 677679866
2 121867616
3 49413198
4 40415982
```

output.txt :

```
1 677679866
2 243735232
3 148239594
4 161663928
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
awk '{ print $1, $1 * $2 }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '$0=$1" "$1*$2' input.txt 
1 677679866
2 243735232
3 148239594
4 161663928
```

But you can do it many ways, here is a `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -ape 's/$F[1]/$F[0]*$F[1]/e' input.txt
1 677679866
2 243735232
3 148239594
4 161663928
```

You can make change inplace, by using `-i` option:

```
$ perl -i.bak -ape 's/$F[1]/$F[0]*$F[1]/e' input.txt
```